# How to convert a SQL with multiple left joins to an Entity Framework LINQ statement using Include methods (No Join methods)?

Tags: c#, sql, entity-framework, linq, linq-to-entities

I am trying to convert this SQL statement to a corresponding EF6 LINQ statement which uses Include methods (no Join Methods) and I am unable to get the LINQ statement right. Using LinqPad. Appreciate any help.

**SQL:**

```
SELECT c.CustomerName, o.Description, co.CountryName, ci.CityName
FROM Customer c
LEFT JOIN [Order] o ON c.CustId = o.CustId
LEFT JOIN Country co ON co.CountryId = o.CountryId
LEFT JOIN City ci ON ci.CityId = o.CityId
```

**My try:**

```
сustomers.Include(c => c.Orders)
         .Select(c => new { c.CustomerName, orders = c.Orders })
         .AsEnumerable()
         .Select(c => new { c.CustomerName, c.orders ... ? })
         .Dump();
```

**DDL:**

The order table has 3 foreign keys to the the corresponding tables.

```
CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Customer](
    [CustId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustomerName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Customer] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [CustId] ASC )

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Order](
    [OrderId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CustId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Description] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
    [CountryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CityId] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Order] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [OrderId] ASC 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[Country](
    [CountryId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CountryName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_Country] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [CountryId] ASC ) 

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[City](
    [CityId] [int] NOT NULL,
    [CityName] [varchar](50) NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_City] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(   [CityId] ASC )
```

Comment: You can basically 2 options: write 2 joins explicitly (I'd start here to understand the schema, resulting query, and overall feasibility) or define navigation properties so let EF to write those 2 joins for you.

Comment: IIRC `Include()` doesn't mean a join, it's used by the lazy lading mechanism to indicate which entities to load eagerly.

Comment: Anything except navigation properties (not `Inlcude`s) is not a real EF solution. Start with proper model and something like `from c in сustomers from o in c.Orders let co = o.Country let ci = o.City select new { desired c, o, co and ci, properties }`

Comment: And why you join starting with Customers? That will include customers without orders (so nulls in last 3 columns), is that intended?

Comment: .Include() does translate into left joins if you do not constraint the entries to non-null properties. pure .Include() calls will literally do what you need. Just do all the includes yourself and do the .Select call afterwards with navigation properties.

Comment: @DevilSuichiro `Includes` are irrelevant in projection queries (they are ignored).

Comment: @Evk: I agree, OP rather should start from Orders and join to get order.Customer, order.Country and order.City

Comment: @abatishchev If start with orders, simple select should do (`.Select(c => new {c.Description, c.Customer.Name, c.Customer.City.Name })` (assuming all navigation properties are in place)

Answer (score 2):

You have basically 2 options:

- write the joins explicitly:

  ```
  var q = from c in db.Customer
          join o in db.Order on c.CustId = o.CustId into oj // join
          from o in oj.DefaultIfEmpty()                     // left join
          join co in db.Country on o.CountryId equals co.CountryId into coj
          from co in coj
          join ci in db.City on o.CityId = ci.CityId into cij
          from ci in cij
          select new
          {
              c.CustomerName, o.Description, co.CountryName, ci.CityName
          };
  ```
- or define the [navigation properties](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj591620(v=vs.113).aspx) and let EF to write those 2 joins for you:

  ```
  var q = from c in db.Customer      // .Include(c => c.Orders) ?
          from o in c.Orders         // .DefaultIfEmpty() ?
          select new
          {
              c.CustomerName,
              o.Description,
              o.Country.CountryName, // those two are the (navigation) properties on the Order class
              o.City.CityName
          };

  public class Order
  {
      public Customer Customer { get; set; }

      public City City { get; set; }

      // public Country Country { get; set; }
  }

  internal class OrderConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<Order>
  {
      public OrderConfiguration()
      {
          // EF fluent API goes here
      }
  }
  ```

To follow the recommendations from comments:

```
var q = from o in db.Orders
        select new
        {
            o.Description,
            o.Customer.CustomerName,
            o.City.CityName,
            o.City.Country.CountryName
        };
```

See also:

- [Move Configurations to Separate Class in Code-First](http://www.entityframeworktutorial.net/code-first/move-configurations-to-seperate-class-in-code-first.aspx)
- [ef-fluent-api](/questions/tagged/ef-fluent-api)

Comment: And I would start with #2 to better understand the cardinality of relationships. There is no need to know if the required joins are inner/outer.

Comment: @IvanStoev: I would start with #1 just because configuring NP is additional work/time and requires additional skills and sometimes schema changes (the worse case scenario, of course). But this is quite subjective. Going forward I would start with #2 right away.

Comment: Additional work which is worth enough. Just look at the two queries you wrote. Anyway, since you provided the #2, you got my vote :)

Comment: Yes, navigation properties are always preferable. Joins aren't only verbose, they're also error prone. I've seen bugs caused by joining wrong Id values.